# Filter full path in Hierarchy chart Power BI

Tags: powerbi, hierarchy

I am creating a family tree using a Hierarchy Chart by Akvelon.
I have added one table under the chart to present the people's data.

When I select any node it will filter the selected person only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxBUN.png)

but I want to filter the full path of nods under this person.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FasBI.png)

any idia how to make it?

Raw Data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMEyc.png)

Comment: I am trying to solve it by adding a new column to show the path:
ChildPath = PATH(Relations[ID],Relations[FatherID])
the result will be:
3 Abdulaziz 1|2|3
where I can filter using this column, but in the next step I want to click in the node, not by filter tap

Comment: Can you share what your raw data looks like?

Comment: I just added the raw data picture